# Why does jQuery give me an error 'has no method sortable'?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a fiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/WULsZ/1/

I load jQuery first and the code is pretty much straight from the sample so I'm puzzled as to why I'm getting an error

Comment: if a method doesn't exist, its because it didn't get loaded. if you know you loaded it, and the browser still thinks it wasnt, then you should begin investigating whether you correctly included the files (tags are correct, includes are in the correct order, etc)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WULsZ/3/

You have to include jQuery Core, then jQuery UI.

```
<script src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12337149/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12337149/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

If you include jQuery UI it will try to extend the jQuery Core, and if you include jQuery Core it will overwrite any previous instance of jQuery Core (including the extended jQuery UI code).

Documentation: http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/

Comment: Any reason for the down vote? I'd just appreciate knowing what I've got wrong :)

Answer (score 2):

Here you go **working demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/WULsZ/7/

Hope this helps, cheers

Missing:

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

**Jquery Code**

```
$(function () {
    $("#sortable").sortable();
    $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});​
```

Comment: Your **demo** is including two copies of jQuery Core and jQuery UI, just FYI.